# vscode C/C++ Extension: Error squiggles when doing: sizeof(int)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using VSCODE in adittion with the C/C++ Extension from Microsoft as a code editor in order to have a more modern code editor than the one my game engine delivers (a code editor from the early 2000s). So I just use vscode to program, I don't compile my code with it.

The problem is that the extension marks correct statements as incorrect:
In my case, I get error squiggles for the simple statement: sizeof(int)
Intellisense says: "Expression expected C/C++ (29)".
[image: Here's a screenshot of this case:]

Does anyone of you know what is wrong?
[image: Here is a screenshot of my configuration:]

Thanks in advance.

I already tried changing the Intellisense mode from msvc-x64 (legacy) to other ones, but the problem still persists.

Comment: This code is not correct. `sizeof` is a built-in keyword and should not be redefined as a macro.

Comment: Hello, thank's for your response. That redefinition comes from the engine itself. The engine uses a custom programming langauge called lite-C, but still is that language very simular to C. But even if I use _sizeof, the error remains.

Comment: Well, if the engine uses custom programming language called lite-C then you should not expect C/C++ parser to deal with it properly. `sizeof`  is a standard built-in, while `_sizeof` is something unknown.

Comment: Ok, yes, in this case youre right. I didn't know that _sizeof is something unknown in 'the real C/C++ world'. Thank's for your help :)

Comment: Or you can try Express version (<=2017) or Community editions of current VS, but language compatibility would be problem still and Code is lighter, faster and better IDE, but VS is easier to maintain, create projects, has form editor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` if a built-in keyword, it should never be redefined as a macro. The macro is expanded to a function (I believe `_sizeof` is a function). The macro expansion looks something like this:

```c
(int)_sizeof(int);
```

The error you get comes from the argument passed. The macro passed a bare data type in a function call (_sizeof(*int*)), when in reality arguments to a function in a function call must always be expressions. That is why you got the error "Expected an expression".

One solution could be to place some code like this (at the beginning of your code):

```c
#ifdef sizeof
#undef sizeof
#endif
```

Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, now vscode does not throw the error :)
Now I just have to figure out how to stop the engine from compiling these lines as this throws real errors, but still thank you very much^^